# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require expo

Tags: react-native, expo, require

I am getting this error in my expo project

```html
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.228:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:479020:3 in global code
```

I tried the fixes I could find but none of them worked for me. I tried clearing the cache, creating a new project and copy and pasting the file of the existing project but I still get the same issue. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe this is related to the expo version,
Check out the package.json file, and upgrade to the latest expo version.
And be sure to have node v14 at least (it's better to upgrade v16).

Comment: I have`"expo": "^45.0.0"` and my node is up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually clear the caches ,

1. Open your project folder.
2. Manually delete all the node modules.
3. Then reinstall all of them by using the `npm install` command in your
   terminal.

Comment: I manually deleted the node_modules folder and run npm install but the issue still persit